# How to cast int digit to char without loosing digit value in c#

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Mabby it's a stupid question, but how can I cast digit of type int to digit of type char?

Standard conversion OPs doesn't do this:

```
int x = 5;
char myChar = Convert.ToChar(5); // myChar is now a unicode character
char secondChar = (char)x; // again I get a unicode character, not a digit '5'
```

I need this because I have a method that returns `IEnumerable` of `Char` and I need to return a collection of `ints` somehow.

For instance:

```
int[] {1, 2, 3}
```

convert to

```
char[] {'1', '2', '3'}
```

Is it possible to do such a conversion in C#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `48` to your `int` value before converting to `char`:

```
char c = (char)(i + 48);
```

Or for `int[]` -> `char[]` conversion:

```
var source = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var results = source.Select(i => (char)(i + 48)).ToArray();
```

It works, because `'0'` character in [ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) has `48` value. But it will work only if your `int` values is between `0` and `9`.

Comment: For clarity, how about `char c = (char)(i + '0');`?

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge Great comment. That would make the code much more readable!

Answer (score 3):

If you know for sure that the values are in the 0 .. 9 range (both inclusive), you can slightly improve efficiency by making use of a *bitwise or*, instead of addition:

```
(char) ('0' | i);
```

this works since `'0'` has as binary codepoint `0011 0000`, and the ten digits thus all are between `0011 0000` and `0011 1001`.

You can thus convert an `IEnumerable<int>` to an `IEnumerable<char>` with:

```
data.Select(i => (char) ('0' | i));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourInts = new int[]{1,2,3};
var result = yourInts.Select(x=>x.ToString()[0]).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :
(char) (i + '0')

Example:
var i = 8;
var c = (char) (i + '0');//Gives '8'