# How to store and represent an int value as a char (C#)

Tags: c#, .net

Im not sure if the title is well explained.
What I mean is getting this done:

```
int i = 3;
char id = (char)i:
Console.Writeline(i);
Console.Writeline(id);
```

and then getting the output in Console:

3

3

But (obviously) I get the output:

[image]

I would like to be able to store as a character the same value of the int variable, not the associated symbol code.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552083/how-to-cast-int-digit-to-char-without-loosing-digit-value-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cast int digit to char without loosing digit value in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552083/how-to-cast-int-digit-to-char-without-loosing-digit-value-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to do this, but if it's to save space you might want to consider `short` (16 bits) over `int` (32 bits).  Granted, how words are stored in memory is another subject, but done correctly you can save the memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean an integer in the range 0 thru 9, then offset the value by the character code for the zero **character** in ASCII - which happens to be 48, but there's no need to know that here - just use the character itself:

```cs
int i = 3;
char id = (char)('0' + i);
```

If you mean any integer: `ToString()` is your friend (there isn't a `char` that can display the value of `42` or `-3`, for example, since they need multiple characters).

Comment: Deleted comment because /I/ did the thing that bugs me that people do:  confusing encodings and character sets.  This is the tried and true answer.

Answer (score 2):

`i.ToString()` is what you are looking for.

`(char)i` converts the value using the ASCII tables, 3 meaning ETX - End of TeXt and therefore showing you a weird symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the int value to a string first. If you still need it as a char, you can
just place the string value inside a char variable by converting it. It would look like that:

```
int number = 3;
 string convertedNumber = Convert.ToString(number);
 char getChar = Convert.ToChar(convertedNumber);
 Console.WriteLine(getChar);
```