# How to convert char[] to string without getting weird results (weird signs in the string)?

Tags: c#

As the title says, when I convert `char[]` to string I get weird string.
I read that it happens because the strings length is not equal to the number of bytes received.
but i don't know how to fix that.
here's what i did, i tried several ways

```
class Time
{
    private int hour;
    private int min;
    private int sec;
    public Time(int h,int m,int s)
    {
        this.hour = h;
        this.min = m;
        this.sec = s;
    }
    public int GetHour()
    {
        return this.hour;
    }
    public int GetMin()
    {
        return this.min;
    }
    public int GetSec()
    {
        return this.sec;
    }
    public double GetTimeDiff(Time t)
    {
        double hour = Math.Abs(this.hour - t.GetHour())*60;
            double min = Math.Abs(this.min - t.GetMin());
            double sec=((double)(Math.Abs(this.sec-t.GetSec())))/60.0;
            return min + sec+hour;         
    }  
    public Time GetCurrentTime()
    {
        return new Time(this.hour, this.min, this.sec);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        char[] arr = new char[8];
    
       arr= "00:00:00".ToArray();
        
        if (this.hour >= 10)
        {
            arr[0] = (char)(this.hour / 10);
            arr[1] = (char)(this.hour % 10);
        }
        else
        {
            arr[1] = (char)(this.hour);
        }
        if (this.min >= 10)
        {
            arr[3] = (char)(this.min / 10);
            arr[4] = (char)(this.min % 10);
        }
        else
        {
            arr[4] = (char)(this.min);
        }
        if (this.sec >= 10)
        {
            arr[6] = (char)(this.sec / 10);
            arr[7] = (char)(this.sec % 10);
        }
        else
        {
            arr[7] = (char)(this.sec);
        }
        string str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            str += arr[i].ToString();
        }
        return str;
    }  
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the proper value

Comment: Oh well yeah you right, I mean what I posted is not my full function because i thought it won't matter but apparently it is. 
Here's is the full function, that is in Time class, and this function suppost to return the time in format "hh:mm:ss" , I edit the question

Comment: can you provide full class

Comment: You seem to not know how to convert a digit to a `char`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552083/how-to-cast-int-digit-to-char-without-loosing-digit-value-in-c-sharp) should answer your question

Comment: Oh thanks gentelmans, all i had to do was +48 in every int , thanks

Comment: Side note: this is not Java. Don't use `GetX` methods, that's what properties are for

Answer (score 0):

you can do this instead of `(char)(this.hour / 10)`

```
(this.hour / 10).ToString()[0]
```

Or do this.

```
(char)(this.hour/10 + 48)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private string ArrayToString(char[] arr)
{
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
return enc.GetString(arr);
}
```

Maybe use Default encoding in windows instead of ASCII

Answer (score 0):

Your entire time class already exists in the framework, as DateTime. It supports hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds, it can partake in maths operations and format itself according to any format string. There is no need to reinvent this wheel. You might, alternatively, take a look at TimeSpan; another framework class that represents a time period, and also supports a lot of operations. DateTime is intended to represent a moment in time, TimeSpan represents a period of time. Use whichever is more appropriate for your needs