# C#--Counting the number of occurrences of a single digit(int) in a string--not working with int to char converted Variable

Tags: c#, linq, char, type-conversion, integer

I'm trying to count the number of times an int appears in a string

```
            int count = numbers
            .Where(x => x == '0')
            .Count();
```

If I type in the literal number I want to check for as seen above '0' it works.
But I want to use this as a method where I can check for other digits. This, unfortunately, doesn't work when I convert an int to a char and insert the digit variable

```
char digit = Convert.ToChar(0);
            int count= numbers
                .Where(x => x == digit)
                .Count();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `0.ToString()` instead of `Convert`

Comment: if I do that, I get the error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'

Comment: @GuruStron You mean `0.ToString()[0]` so that it's the `char`.  Or better yet just `'0' + digit`

Comment: @juharr yes, that was added in the answer.

Comment: `int count = numbers.Where(x => int.TryParse(x.ToString(), out int numb) && numb == yournumber).Count();`

Comment: What's `numbers` a `string`?

Comment: As a routine, you could do something like; `public static int GetNumberCount(int number, string testString) => testString.Where(x => int.TryParse(x.ToString(), out int num) && num == number).Count();` and usage of: `Console.WriteLine(GetNumberCount(0, numbers));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Convert.ToChar(Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tochar?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToChar_System_Int32_) returns Unicode character equivalent to the value of passed int. For example it will convert `65` to `A`:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(65)); // prints "A"
```

If I understand your requirement correctly you can call `ToString` and take first char of resulting string instead of `Convert.ToChar(0)`:

```
char digit = 0.ToString()[0]
```

Or as [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552083/how-to-cast-int-digit-to-char-without-loosing-digit-value-in-c-sharp):

```
char c = (char)(i + 48);
```

Comment: if I do ToString() I get the error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'

But the (char)(i+48) works! Thank you!

Comment: @juliana please check the code carefully.

Comment: @juliana it is not only `ToString`, there is also an indexer `[0]` applied.

Answer (score 3):

Convert.ToChar(0) converts you bit representation to the according to the character encoding table (e.g. [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)) . 0 in this case is a [Null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). Whereas bit representation of a '0' character is 48 according to the  table

You can use this snippet to compare you int digit to the chars

```
 string numbers = "33";
 int digit = 3;
 int count = numbers
                // '0' -'0' (48 - 48) will give you 0 int value, 
                // '1' - '0' (49 - 48) will give you 1 etc.
                .Where(x => x - '0' == digit) 
                .Count();
```

but keep  in mind that you digit might be greater than 9, then it would take more than one character and this is going a bit different problem.